# PLS-00352 AND PLS-00201 Over DB Link

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, dblink

I have a Oracle Database `12c Release 12.1.0.1.0` - 64bit Production database. I'm trying to call a procedure on a Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Product database over a public dblink (DEVICE_201). When I attempt the call I get -

Error starting at line : 1 in command -

```
 BEGIN 
    proc_test@DEVICE_201; 
    END;
```

Error report -

> > ORA-06550: line 2, column 1:  PLS-00352: Unable to access another
> >     database 'DEVICE_201'
> >
> > ORA-06550: line 2, column 1:  PLS-00201: identifier
> >     'PROC_TEST@DEVICE_201' must be declared
> >
> > ORA-06550: line 2, column 1:  PL/SQL: Statement ignored
> >
> > 6550. 00000 - "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>
> *Cause: Usually a PL/SQL compilation error. 
>   *Action:

Here are the table and procedure definitions on the remote db:

```
CREATE TABLE "TEST"("TEST" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE))

 -------------------------------------------

 create or replace PROCEDURE PROC_TEST AS 
    BEGIN
     INSERT INTO TEST (TEST) VALUES (SYSDATE);
     COMMIT;
    END PROC_TEST;
```

This is how I am calling it from the local db:

```
BEGIN
proc_test@DEVICE_201;
END;
```

We have this configuration working at other locations and I have run this test code at one of those. I think this comes down to a permissions issue, but the permissions for this location are the same as others as far as I can see.

Comment: There was a bug about calling stored procedures on 10XE.  Does this work on other 10XE databases?

Comment: Are you able to run `select * from dual@device_201;` without issues?

Comment: I'm double checking the db version issue. Yes  I can run select * from dual@device_201; without issue

Comment: @kevinsky I set up another environment calling the 10XE proc from 12c. I get the same error. I'm starting to think this might actually be a bug. Do you have any more info on that bug. My searches have not turned up a bug.

Comment: @user6656451 I installed a 10 XE as a bridge between Oracle 8i and Oracle 11g.  I found that I could not call stored procs on 10 from 11 over a database link.  This was a few years ago but I believe it was a bug that was not going to be patched as it was XE

Comment: I'm searching for a bug related to this, but I'm not able to find one. I can't really go to my boss and say "it's a bug" without being able to actually point at one. Is anyone else able to find one?

Comment: I am able to execute the procedure from a 10g Standard version. Is there an incompatibility between 12c and 10g XE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting same error when using db link between 12c and 10g(10.2.0.1.0). Then found this article: https://82star.wordpress.com/2011/09/06/clientserver-interoperability-support-id-207303-1/ . There's a line: "For database link connections between 11.1 (or higher) and 10.2 the 10g end MUST be at 10.2.0.2 (or higher) in order to use PLSQL between those versions. See Note:4511371.8 for more details."
So I upgraded 10g to 10.2.0.5.0 and was able to execute stored procedures via dblink

Comment: Sorry for the too late comment : 

I have four databases DB-1, DB-2, DB3 and DB-4.
DB-4 is not directly connected to DB-1 so i am using combination of DB links and synonyms. Every things works fine till DB-3 but not at DB-4. I get PLS-00352 at DB-4. 
All my databases are Oracle 11gR2 : 11.2.0.4.0