# Altering user password of remote database user using REST API in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle-apex

I need to change remote database user's password (database changes dynamically based on selection) using REST API in oracle Apex ,is that  possible ?

My code is

```
 create or replace PROCEDURE PASSWORD_CHANGE(P2_DATABASE VARCHAR2,P2_USERAME VARCHAR2 ,P2_PASSWORD VARCHAR2) IS
SQL_STRING VARCHAR(500);
BEGIN
 SQL_STRING:=' begin accout_change@'||P2_DATABASE||'LINK('''||P2_USERAME||''','''||P2_PASSWORD||'''); end; ';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQL_STRING;

dbms_output.put_line(SQL_STRING);
END;
```

its showing error as

ORA-06550: line 1, column 8:
PLS-00352: Unable to access another database 'SYS_DBLINK'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 8:
PLS-00201: identifier 'ACCOUT_CHANGE@SYS_DBLINK' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 8:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: Hi Dan Mcghan,Please find my code which wrote

Answer (score 0):

By remote, do you mean connected via database link? To alter passwords, you need the `alter user` privilege granted to a user that exists in the database where you want to change the password.

You'd probably be best off creating a stored procedure that does the password change on each remote database that's owned by a user with the `alter user` privilege. Then you'd grant execute on the procedure to whatever user you're connecting as over the DB link.

Comment: i created a form in Oracle Apex and when  i click the submit button then Stored Procedure runs that  changes the user password over dblike but iam getting the error as "ORA-06550: line 1, column 8: PLS-00352: Unable to access another database &#x27;SYS_DBALINK"

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39495114/pls-00352-and-pls-00201-over-db-link

Comment: Hi  Dan McGhan,its working while executing the procedure from SQL Developer but showing above error while executing from Oracle Apex

Comment: How, exactly, was the DB link was created? Generate the DDL, remove any sensitive info, and share it. How are you connecting to SQL Developer (what user)? How did you do the grant to the stored procedure? Start with a test stored procedure that just has `null;` in the execution section. Once you get that working then change to the code you want to use to see if that causes any issues.