PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_UTILITY.EXEC_DDL_STATEMENT@DB_LINK' must be declared
I am trying to run a DDL statement, from an Oracle database on a Postgres database, through the procedure DBMS_UTILITY.EXEC_DDL_STATEMENT like this:
begin
dbms_utility.exec_ddl_statement@DB_LINK(
'truncate table example1;'
);
end;
/

However, I am getting this error:
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 1:
PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_UTILITY.EXEC_DDL_STATEMENT@DB_LINK' must be
declared
ORA-06550: line 2, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Why is it outputting that I must declare the procedure? I did not find similar question anywhere.

Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/39495114/1509264

Does your Postgres database have a procedure called dbms_utility.exec_ddl_statement? Or did you mean to use the Oracle procedure and use truncate table example1@dblink as an argument?

The second option, but I changed it to "begin
dbms_utility.exec_ddl_statement(
'truncate table example1@DB_LINK;'
);
end;
/" and now it says "ORA-02021: DDL operations are not allowed on a remote database".

When I run this select "SELECT *
FROM USER_PROCEDURES
WHERE object_name like '%dbms_utility%';", I cannot find the procedure. Could it be the motive why it does not work? And how would I add it to the database?

Your answer is in your previous comment: Oracle doesn't allow DDL commands to be executed over a database link. Your query didn't find anything in USER_PROCEDURES in part because when quoted ('%dbms_utility%') the object name becomes case sensitive and must be given in upper case.

Additionally dbms_utility typically is not a user object but can be found in dba_objects or all_objects.

I think the main problem was that I was trying to execute the DDL statement from an Oracle database on a Postgres database. I found at different posts that it would work through the syntax in my question, but I have decided to just create a job on the Postgres side to truncate the table before the Oracle job executes the INSERT statement in the Postgres table.
